# (#100) Invalid parameter OAuthException when creating event using Graph API Explorer

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Graph API Explorer to try and work out how to create a user event prior to coding it for real in Objective-C for an iOS app.

I have obtained an auth token which contains `user_event`, `publish_actions` and `create_event` permissions.

I am `POST`ing a request to `https://graph.facebook.com/12345678/events` with parameters of `name` set to `Tester 2` and `start_date` set to `2013-06-27`

In response I get

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Invalid parameter", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: It's because you need to use `start_time` instead of `start_date`.  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

Comment: Brilliant!  - Thanks - funny how you can't see something when it's staring you in the face.  If you want to change your comment to an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Promoted to answer.  Thanks!  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you need to use `start_time` instead of `start_date`.

Doc reference:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

Comment: <facepalm>  Helped me too.  +1